# Exception : Illegal characters in path

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am using Path.GetTempPath function to get temp file path to store xml file at temporary location. At first this works successfully but for next run this gives a exception as "Illegal characters in file path".

```
  string filepath = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath();
            if (Interface.IsDebugMode)
            {
                xmlRepository.SaveDataToFile(filepath + @"\\savedFile.xml", true);
            }
```

Comment: pretty clear you need to check your path. Plus we can't really tell without any code

Comment: this works fine for first run??

Comment: Some amount of code is required, along with what you're trying to name the file.

Answer (score 3):

This should not work at all

```
    xmlRepository.SaveDataToFile(filepath + @"\\savedFile.xml", true);
```

it needs to be This

```
    xmlRepository.SaveDataToFile(filepath + "\\savedFile.xml", true);
```

or this

```
    xmlRepository.SaveDataToFile(filepath + @"\savedFile.xml", true);
```

but not both And as the comment below says you really should be using this

```
    xmlRepository.SaveDataToFile(Path.Combine(filepath, "savedFile.xml"), true);
```

Comment: For that matter, `xmlRepository.SaveDataToFile(Path.Combine(filepath, "savedFile.xml"), true);`